# Some string problems there

Tags: c++, string, codeblocks

I am making a bot for steam offers. And i need to get every character of a string in a variable, i tried to use vectors but it didn't work. From the string "abc" i got the vectors: 97 98 99. I don't understand what is wrong there..

```
    int v[100], j=0; unsigned i;
string str; cin>>str;
for (i=0; i<str.length(); ++i)
{
    v[i]=str.at(i);
    cout<<str.at(i)<<endl;
    cout<<v[i]<<endl;
}
```

I am new with all this thing, so, please help me a bit. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: please tag your question with the language the code is written in

Comment: When 'a' is cast to an int, it is 97.  Is that what you didn't understand/want?  Why did you store a char as an int?  Instead of `int v[100], j=0;` maybe you wanted `char v[100]; int j=0;`  Alternately, maybe you wanted to cast it back to char before printing  `cout<<(char)str.at(i)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

97, 98, and 99 are the numeric values of characters `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` in the ASCII character set.   So converting them to an `int`, which is what your code does in order to store their values into an array of `int`, will give those values unless your host system operates with a non-compatible character set.

Comment: Oups. That was dumb from me, my bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

change `int v[100]` to `char v[100]`

Answer (score 0):

that's because you declared v as an int, declare it as a char

```
char v[100];
int j=0; 
unsigned i;
string str; 
cin>>str;

for (i=0; i<str.length(); ++i)
{
    v[i]=str.at(i);
    cout<<str.at(i)<<endl;
    cout<<v[i]<<endl;
}
```